# Telerik RadCalendar set focus on more than 1 dates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, calendar, telerik

I want to focus on multiple dates in multiple months in a 3 month wide telerik RadCalendar view on my WPF project. Right now only the current date (today's date) gets highlighted (or focused). I want to focus on other dates too besides today's date. Any suggestions/ideas how to go about it?

Comment: how and why do you want to select the other dates? Based on bound data source, etc.? I think we need more details.

Comment: Yeah. Lets say the birthdates are stored and each birth date is a DateTime type variable. I want to highlight all dates that happen to be birthdays. the birthdates come from a table in sql server. Then after that, if the user selects a particular highlighted birthday on the calendar a textbox gets populated with the nameof the person whose birthdate happens to be the selected date on the calendar. i hope this explains what I intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

First you get your daa from databaase and then Write Following Code

For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows
                    'cdrCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime(dr("Start")))

```
                'Convert.ToDateTime(ddlFromHours.SelectedItem.Text + " " + ddlAMPM.SelectedItem.Text).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm tt")

                If Convert.ToDateTime(dr("Start")).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") <> Convert.ToDateTime(Date.Today).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") Then
                    cdrCalendar.SelectedDates.Add(New RadDate(dr("Start"))) '(dr("Start")))
                End If

            Next
```